# tengo un error a la hora de acceder a la data de mi base de datos sqlite

Tags: base-de-datos, mysqli, flutter, vscode, dart

**SqfliteDatabaseException (DatabaseException(no such table: Usuario (code 1 SQLITE_ERROR): , while compiling: SELECT * FROM Usuario) sql 'SELECT * FROM Usuario' args [])**

ese es el error que me suelta y tengo unos print a la hora que la base de datos se abra, y me aparecen como si ya se hubiera abierto la base de datos, pero me tira tambien un null

```
  Future openDB() async {
    final databasePath = await getDatabasesPath();
    final path = join(databasePath, 'DataBase.db');

    var exist = await databaseExists(path);
    if (!exist) {
      print('creating new copy from assets');

      try {
        await Directory(dirname(path)).create(recursive: true);
      } catch (_) {}

     
      ByteData data = await rootBundle.load(join("assets", "DataBase.db"));
      List<int> bytes =
          data.buffer.asUint8List(data.offsetInBytes, data.lengthInBytes);

     
      await File(path).writeAsBytes(bytes, flush: true);
    } else {
      print("Opening existing database");
    }

    final db = await openDatabase(path);
    print('base de datos abierta');
  }

  //instancia de base de datos
  final Future<Database> database = getDatabasesPath().then((String path) {
    return openDatabase(join(path, 'programa_nutricion.db'));
  });

  Future<List<UsuarioModel>> getUsuario() async {
    final Database db = await database;
    final List<Map<String, dynamic>> map = await db.query('Usuario');

    return map.map((e) => UsuarioModel.fromJson(e)).toList();
  }
}
```

estos son los prints que me tira la consola
cuando llamo la base de datos en la pagina del login

`DatabaseHelper().openDB().then(print);`

```
Restarted application in 803ms.
I/flutter (22864): Opening existing database
I/flutter (22864): base de datos abierta
I/flutter (22864): null
```

Comment: No veo que hayas creado la tabla "Usuarios", te aconsejo que leas la documentación de persistencia de datos https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/persistence/sqlite

Comment: es que la base de datos ya esta creada, la tengo en assets y ya la referencia en el puspect.yaml @JonathanPerez

Comment: Tiene dos nombres diferentes para su database: Database.db y programa_nutricion.db. Elige un nombre.